# Lock variable in python in a loop

Tags: python, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am trying to implement Producer consumer scenario in Python...
The producer is supposed to cease lock variable if the queue is full and release it if it is not full... I am using the lock variable in loop

```
def run(self):
        #mutexProducer.acquire()
        #Entering Critical section
        #print self.queue.qsize()
        while True:
            customer=Customer()
            self.mutex.acquire()# acquire condition variable to see if queue is full
            if self.queue.full():
                print "Queue is full : Cant Enter Critical Section"
                #print "Customer %d is discarded" %(customer.id)
            elif not self.queue.full() :
                print "i am here"
                print self.mutex.release()
                self.mutex.acquire()
                #Critical Section
                self.queue.put(customer)#pushing Customer to queue
                print "Customer %d Enters the Queue with %d service " %(customer.id,customer.serviceTime)
                #critical Section
                self.mutex.release()
```

Does my code lock multiple instances over and over again?? The reason i am asking is i am new to threads and After queue is full, The producer stops creating any process(customer in my case)

Comment: You do know python queue can block the producer and consumer for you out-of-the-box?

Comment: @ReutSharabani I know that... But i am trying to use the mutex variable.... Can anyone explain why is the producer stops producing from above code?? is multiple instances of mutex variable is acquired due to looping such that same number of release is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added some notes on your code, which has some problems:

```
def run(self):
        while True:
            customer=Customer()
            self.mutex.acquire()

            if self.queue.full():
                print "Queue is full : Cant Enter Critical Section"
                # NOTE 1: you have to release mutex here: self.mutex.release()
            elif not self.queue.full():
                # NOTE 2: other threads can enter after releasing the lock
                print self.mutex.release()

                self.mutex.acquire()
                #Critical Section
                self.queue.put(customer)
                print "Customer %d Enters the Queue with %d service " %(
                    customer.id,customer.serviceTime
                )
                self.mutex.release()
```

Alternative to **NOTE 1** (but same motives):

```
def run(self):
        while True:
            customer=Customer()
            self.mutex.acquire()

            if self.queue.full():
                print "Queue is full : Cant Enter Critical Section"

            elif not self.queue.full():
                # NOTE 2: other threads can enter after releasing the lock
                print self.mutex.release()

                self.mutex.acquire()
                #Critical Section
                self.queue.put(customer)
                print "Customer %d Enters the Queue with %d service " %(
                    customer.id,customer.serviceTime
                )
            # Note 1 alternative - release mutex (cancel 'if' branching effect)
            self.mutex.release()
```

I actually fail to understand it's logic. You release the lock allowing threads to check the queue while others thread push to the queue, but you're aassuming the queue isn't thread-safe.

If you are using the queue's thread-safety, than why use mutex to begin with?

**Edit:** The main problem is, as specified, you're acquiring the mutex twice with the producer. You can only acquire the mutex once (at-least if it's a `threading.Lock` object). Try this code in your interperter:

```
>>> import threading
>>> lock = threading.Lock()
>>> lock.acquire()
True
>>> lock.acquire()
```

And see what happens.

Either way, figure out the logic for your critical section. The fixed code (NOTE 1) should prevent the blocking you're experiencing due to not releasing the mutex on the first if branch.

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry sir... Pardon my poor understanding of mutex variable... What i was trying to do is keep acquiring the mutex variable till the queue is full and release it as soon as it got some space in queue... so that producer will keep holding the produce process (customer in my case) and enqueue it in the queue as soon as it gets hold of mutex variable ... IS my understanding illogical?

Comment: suppose the queue is full -> producer takes mutex -> producer tries to take it again (wasn't release) to check if queue is full -> producer blocked. Added an example to the answer.

Comment: @ABC , unless by **the code ** you mean the size (shrib) - I didn't get any code :)

Comment: I tried both your suggestion.. With the first one i get the same problem i did BEFORE and with the second, producer doesnot produce anything at all

Comment: Thanks sir!! i get that we cannot acquire the lock more than once unless it is released... :) i have to modify my logic!!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to use a `Lock` is by using the with statement. It automatically handles the acquisition and release of lock, even if the block exits with an exception.

For instance:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
with lock:
    print "the lock is locked for the duration of this block"
try:
    with lock:
        raise Exception("block exits with an exception")
except Exception:
    pass
assert not lock.locked()
```

It's impossible to substitute the with statement into your code without making a new minor modifications. However, this generally reflects how locks should be used.

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        customer=Customer()
        # enter critical section
        with self.mutex:
            queue_full = self.queue.full()
        # exit critical section
        if queue_full:
            print "Queue is full : Cant Enter Critical Section"
        else:
            print "i am here"
            # enter critical section
            with self.mutex:
                #pushing Customer to queue
                self.queue.put(customer)
            # exit critical section
            print "Customer %d Enters the Queue with %d service " % \
                (customer.id, customer.serviceTime)
```

However, because you have multiple related critical section there is problem that arises if there are multiple producer threads. What happens if one thread checks the state of the queue, exits its critical section, is suspended in favour of another thread, and by the time execution is resumed the queue has become full. The condition that was checked in the earlier critical section no longer holds true. Thus all related actions must be done together in the same critical section. If there is only one producer then this would not be a problem.

Coping with multiple producers:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        customer=Customer()
        if not self.add_customer(customer):
            print "Queue is full: failed to add customer"

def add_customer(self):
    with self.mutex:
        # entire section that checks if the queue is full and then adding the 
        # customer is considered critical
        if not self.queue.full():
            self.queue.put(customer)
            return True # customer added
    return False # customer not added
```

Having looked at the code provided [here](http://shrib.com/random) in one of your comments. I can see you are not using locks correctly. Each co-ordinating thread must have a access to the same lock, as opposed to creating a new separate lock for each thread.

You main method should look something like:

```
def main():
    queue_size=2
    queue=Queue.Queue(maxsize=queue_size)
    print queue.full()

    # scrap the following three lines
    mutexProducer=threading.Lock()#mutex variablaes
    mutexConsumer=thread.allocate_lock()
    mutexTeller=thread.allocate_lock()

    mutex = threading.Lock()
    # producer and scheduler use the same lock
    producer = Producer(queue, mutex)
    scheduler = Scheduler(queue, mutex)

    producer.start()
    scheduler.start()
```

Comment: WELL  i have updated the entire implementation of my code [here](http://shrib.com/random) ...  Thanks for taking time to look at my problem.... I have one Producer ,one scheduler, two consumer in my program... Its part of my assignment.. i have used different lock variables for producer , consumer and scheduler.. However i think that i have not implemented the concept of mutex variable correctly... It would be great if you would take a look at my code.... I will also try with the "with method " and post back once i get the result :)